# Eclipse add library containing class with $ sign

Tags: java, eclipse

I wanna add a library in my project in eclipse, but it contains a class named AdamantiumMenu$PropertyKey and 2 other classes without $ sign in their name, this 2 classes are added successfully but not the first one with $.
Can anyone suggest how I need to proceed to add all the 3 classes ?

I add this code to **pom.xml** :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.primefaces.adamantium</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/adamantium-theme-1.0.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
```

I get this error :

```
09:52:27.961 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] ERROR f.p.s.b.e.CustomExceptionHandler - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/primefaces/adamantium/component/menu/AdamantiumMenu$PropertyKeys
    at org.primefaces.adamantium.component.menu.AdamantiumMenu.getModel(AdamantiumMenu.java:71)
    at org.primefaces.component.menu.BaseMenuRenderer.encodeEnd(BaseMenuRenderer.java:103)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:674)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeAll(UIComponentBase.java:554)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeAll(UIComponentBase.java:550)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeAll(UIComponentBase.java:550)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeAll(UIComponentBase.java:550)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.renderView(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.java:1891)
    at org.apache.myfaces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:313)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:58)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RenderResponseExecutor.execute(RenderResponseExecutor.java:116)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:267)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:200)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:125)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1086)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:659)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1558)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1515)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.primefaces.adamantium.component.menu.AdamantiumMenu$PropertyKeys
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1305)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1157)
    ... 68 more
```

Comment: Well what happened? Is your library in a jar file? Note that these are just inner classes...

Comment: Yes it's a jar file containing a package that contains the 3 classes, and when i execute the code I receive the NoClassFoundException ... AdamantiumMenu$PropertyKey

Comment: It would help if you could show the exact error, what's in the jar file, what the code looks like etc... there isn't enough information at the moment.

Comment: To add to what Jon Skeet commented, a class file with a dollar sign ($) in the name is an inner class. Normally, it shouldn't be a problem using this, unless you don't have the parent class file (AdamantiumMenu.class) on the class path.

Comment: The jar contains : AmdamantiumMenu.class, AdamantiumMenuRenderer.class and the AdamantiumMenu$PropertyKey.class

Comment: So what's your context? Please edit the question to give a lot more information. See http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints

Comment: I'm sorry I don't have my laptop tomorrow I will edit it

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved, I add the class manually to a folder, then I add a source folder (in Build Path) and I give the path of the folder containing all the classes including the inner class.

Answer (score -1):

Java Compiler by default adds `$` sign when the `class` file is generated and if the class contains `inner classes`. Try to create an instance of the `class` before `$` and see if it works.

Try the following:

```
AdamantiumMenu adamantiumMenu = new AdamantiumMenu();
AdamantiumMenu.PropertyKey propertyKey = adamantiumMenu. new PropertyKey();
```

Comment: This isn't about how to use it - it's about an exception due to the class not being found.

Comment: Understand, if it is a library, the reference would be proper. This looks like user code where user is trying to instantiate using the class name with $ in it. Might be a Spring injection or Reflection.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "the reference would be proper" but I wouldn't guess too much given how little context we've got. Better to find out from the OP...